# Can an OpAmp be built without an IC or transistor or a Vacuum tube?

Tags: operational-amplifier

Is it possible to build an OpAmp without using an integrated circuit or a transistor or a vacuum tube?  I wanted to see how it would look on a larger scale before miniaturization on a chip.

I was hoping for a high view of what that would entail, not only that it is logically possible.

@HarrySvensson Thanks. That is what I wanted. I didn't mean to cause a ruckus. I only wanted to see what was going on outside of all the YouTube videos and all the rest. I figured if I could see it with big chunky non-IC parts, I could understand it. Apparently I miscalculated there.

What I should have asked for was an equivalent circuit.  Now I know the keywords to search and have found many.

Comment: You probably can use some vacuum tubes...

Comment: I just added that to the question.

Comment: What will you build it from then? Wood?

Comment: @HarrySvensson I don't see how with the updated restrictions.

Comment: I have no idea.  That's why i asked.  Other electronic parts. Probably not wood though.

Comment: No, you need something active to deal with feed back into the circuit.

Comment: You could probably make a semiconductor using wood if you really tried. It probably wouldn't be wood when you finish though

Comment: @BeB00 You might want to patent the process :)

Comment: What an op-amp really is, is a PID regulator without the I and D part and with an insane amount of P. PID regulators existed before electronics existed... so it's *not impossible*.. , but what you'll end up with is something that you'll throw in the garbage.

Comment: @EugeneSh. You just need to carbonize it, heat the carbon up until it starts semiconducting, and then figure out how to dope it :P

Comment: @HarrySvensson You need an *electrical* PID here, which I doubt existed before electronics. And it has to be a damn *fast* PID.

Comment: @EugeneSh. or just make it into nanotubes, but theres already a lot of prior art on that (https://patents.google.com/?q=carbon+nanotube+transistor) so maybe less fun

Comment: @EugeneSh. This question is so weird/vague, are we talking about electronics or not? "op-amp, but without ic/transistor/vacuum tube" => so... nothing electrical. All active components are thrown out the window, so OP *probably* talks about some *mechanical OP-amp*.... Yeah... I give up..

Comment: Fundamentally, you need something which has gain. The only electronic device which you haven't excluded and that comes to mind is a magnetic amplifier, but even that needs some other electronics to make it work

Comment: I think I understand what OP *really* wants, he just explained it very bad (I think). If OP wants to understands how OP-amps works, then maybe OP should [play around with a simulator](http://tinyurl.com/ybpbjtcw).

Comment: @HarrySvensson Thanks.  That is what I wanted.  I didn't mean to cause a ruckus.  I only wanted to see what was going on outside of all the YouTube videos and all the rest.  I figured if I could see it with big chunky non-IC parts, I could understand it.  Apparently I miscalculated there.

Comment: @johnny if you want to go down to the lowest possible level, you can make an opamp out of discrete transistors. Theres a very good "teardown" of a 741 opamp at http://www.righto.com/2015/10/inside-ubiquitous-741-op-amp-circuits.html

Comment: Given the selected correct answer, you may also want to look into the beginning part of an op-amp: the differential pair. This is generally the first stage of the guts of an op-amp. Op-amp circuits take this first stage and then continue amplifying the signal more. Just a differential pair alone will give you a very basic low-amplification op-amp. 
https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/the-basic-mosfet-differential-pair/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think I understand what OP really wants. If OP wants to understands how Op-Amps works, then maybe OP should [play around with a simulator](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2010.20027730826997%2057%205%2050%0Av%2096%20256%2096%20112%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%2096%20256%2096%20304%200%0Ar%2096%20112%20192%20112%200%201000%0Ar%20192%20144%20336%20144%200%203000%0Aw%20336%20144%20336%20192%200%0Aw%20192%20112%20192%20144%200%0Aw%20192%20144%20192%20176%200%0Aw%2096%20256%20192%20256%200%0Aw%20192%20208%20192%20256%200%0Aa%20192%20192%20336%20192%208%2015%20-15%201000000%20-0.00014888106654952721%200%20100000%0AO%20336%20192%20400%20192%200%0Ao%200%2064%200%204098%205%200.025%200%202%200%203%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204098%2020%200.00009765625%201%201%0A). In this particular online simulator, OP can actually see the current and the voltages and how everything behaves. Things which are difficult/tedious/impossible to do without an oscilloscope or other measurement devices.

After you've clicked the link, then you can browse **many** other Op-Amp designs under circuits > Op-Amps.

The one in the link was the circuits > Op-Amps > Amplifiers > Inverting amplifier.

Comment: *I think I understand what OP really wants* And you have my respect for finding out what OP was really asking because this was a very poorly asked question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Part of learning is learning what you don't know what to ask for.

Comment: @johnny Don't forget to watch [this video by Dave Jones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7FYHt5XviKc). It certainly helped me when I was where you are now.

Comment: @HarrySvensson I clicked that Dave Jones video half expecting to find an introduction into how to be more emphatic and aware of cues on what people want. Clearly you are skilled in that, too. :-)

Comment: @Prof.Falken Online I may be that, in real life I'm struggling ;)

Answer (score 15):

Opamps have power gain, so one way or another you need a external power source and active components.  You have ruled out the usual active components used for amplification in electronics, which are transistors and vacuum tubes.

You therefore need to get clever and find other ways to amplify.  That means you need to be able to control a large amount of power by variations of a small amount of power.  Some possibilities:

A motor driving a rheostat.

LEDs controlling LDRs (light dependent resistors).

Pressure-controlled water flow valves.

Pressure-controlled pneumatic valves.

A gasoline engine with the control being the throttle.

A mechanically controlled adjustable transformer, like a variac.

A electrical generator where the power input is the mechanical rotation of the shaft, and the control is done by changing the field winding current.

Once you have something that can amplify, you still have to use it, or several of them in the right configuration, to make a opamp.  This is just like a transistor isn't a opamp, but multiple transistors arranged the right way (with some passive parts) can be a opamp.

Answer (score 6):

In principle you could design and build an op-amp with magnetic amplifiers or one that operated mechanically. Amplifiers are amplifiers, so at a high level they'd be designed on identical principles. The devil, of course, would be in the details.

Mechanical analog computers have been around for centuries, and mag-amps pre-date vacuum tubes and silicon ICs. The literature on them is mature, and designing an op-amp with these technologies could be done.

Answer (score 2):

The US Navy used magnetic amplifiers to servo the aiming points of 16" guns even as the battleship underwent mild roll/pitch/yaw.

I recall the power levels were 100,000 watts or about 1,500 horsepower.

Answer (score 1):

You could always build circuits using [fluidics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluidics). You would use hydraulic fluids instead of electrons, and it was a hot research area before the integrated circuit was invented.

Comment: You still need to interface it to electrical system.

Comment: No, the OP didn't say anything about an "electrical" system.

Comment: Opamp is an electronic component by definition.

Comment: I disagree. An **operational amplifier** is an amplifier that is reasonably used to perform an **operation**, serving as the basis for some form of computational device. The OP didn't say anything that restricted the question to electronic devices, and it seems that some other contributors agree with my broad definition of the question.

Comment: This is not about *your* definition, but about the common definition, given in credible sources. I really don't see a place for argument here. I made my point.

Comment: Well, my definition is a common definition that appears to be shared by (at least) Olin and schadjo so maybe the question is not about *your* definition.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but there is a reason op amps are used so widely with chips.

You could build one with vacuum tubes or transistors.  But the problem is even two components like that of the same model can have pretty varied functionality, and it changes with temperature.

One advantage of an op amp on an IC is that (1) the components are more likely to be very well matched, since they are on the same die, and (2) they are at exactly the same temperature.  Look up "long-tailed pair", a classic op amp input design, which takes advantage of these.

If you are wondering why you don't see op amps that aren't on a chip, or at least a couple of (matched) transistors, the answer is that op amps became far more practical to build with the coming of analog ICs.  If you are asking is there some way to build an op amp (equivalent) without silicon involved, people have given some ideas above.